# I need to send user a copy of the placed order in the form

Tags: php

Iam using the following php code in my order form

I need to send user a copy of his/her placed order other than the owner mail. I don't know how to write code in $recepient for sending a copy to user also. I need to use "$Email" for the user email id.
Please give me suggestion for writing code.

My php code for order form is as follows:

```
       <?php
      $Email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));

      $Name = $_POST['Name'];
      $Email = $_POST['Email'];
      $Business = $_POST['Business'];
      $phone= $_POST['phone'];
      $productid= $_POST['productid'];
      $producttype= $_POST['producttype'];
      $Productquantity= $_POST['Productquantity'];
      $Shippingaddress= $_POST['Shippingaddress'];
      $Message = $_POST['Message'];

     $formcontent= 
    "$Name is sending you a request for the product enquiry.  \n
       Details of  the Product Enquiry person are as follows- \n
     Name: $Name \n
     Contact Number: $phone \n
     Email: $Email \n
     Business Name/Company Name: $Business \n
     Product Id: $productid \n
     Product Type: $producttype \n
     Product Quantity: $Productquantity \n
     Comment: $Message \n
     Shipping Address: $Shippingaddress";

     $recipient = "info@domain.com";
     $subject = "Request for Product Enquiry";
     $mailheader = "From: $Name \r\n";
     mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "<h4><font color='#2A007D'><strong><center>Thank You $Name !
                We have received your Order details and 
              we will contact you as soon as possible. 
             <br>Your Order details has been sent to your Email also.
             </center></strong></font></h4>";
     ?>
```

Comment: Just send it again. Copy the last line (`mail($user_mail, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);` and you're done...

Comment: Why are you using `stripslashes`? Are you **sure** you have magic quotes enabled? If not you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `mail()` again with the user's email address, so:

`mail($Email, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);`

although you may want to change the message text too.

Comment: What is `$Name`? This will need to be a valid email address and well formed as per [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) if you're using it as the From: header

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

 if(!$mail)
  {
     echo <h4><font color='red'>Failed</font></h4>;
  }
  else
  {
     echo "<h4><font color='#2A007D'><strong><center>Thank You $Name ! We have received your Order details and we will contact you as soon as possible. <br>Your Order details has been sent to your Email also.</center></strong></font></h4>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I have placed the line mail($user_mail, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader); but user is not receiving any mail

Comment: `$mailheader = "From:".$Name;` alter this

Comment: I used the following code, its working:   But in the user email it is showing as "unknown sender".................$subject = "Request for Product Enquiry";
$headers = 'From: '.$Name."\r\n".
'Cc: '.$Email."\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers) or die("Error!");